# How do I make a command that makes the status change in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command for my bot in discord.js. What it's supposed to do it, whenever the admin of the server uses it, It'll change the status. I tried making it, but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('!status')) {
   const prefix = '!';
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    if (member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
    const activity = args.splice(2);
    client.user.setActivity(activity);
    }
    else {
      message.channel.send('You\'re not the admin of the server or bot!')
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `client.user.setActivity()` expects a string, but you provided an array. Did you mean `args[1]` instead of `args.splice(2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is `member` is not defined, if you want ti to be the message author, you can use `message.member` instead.

The second problem is `activity` is an array, it [needs to be a string](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity) or an [`ActivityOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ActivityOptions) object. You either want to use the first element of `args` as the status, or if you want to accept more than one words, `join` them by space instead.

Check the code below, I've added a few comments too:

```js
const prefix = '!';

client.on('message', (message) => {
  // if the message doesn't start with the prefix or the author is a bot, exit early
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  // create an args variable that slices off the prefix and splits it into an array
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  // create a command variable by taking the first element in the array
  // and removing it from args
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'status') {
    // if the message author has no permission, send a message and exit
    if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR'))
      return message.channel.send('Your not the Admin of the server or bot!');

    // if there are more than one words as the status, join them again
    const activity = args.join(' ');
    client.user.setActivity(activity);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you had to fix up.

First, like what Lioness100 said, the `setActivity` method expects a string for an argument, not an array. If you wanted to simply remove the command, then you can simply do something like `const activity = message.content.slice(7);`

Second, you cannot simply grab the `member` since the program will have no idea which member you're expecting. You'll have to grab the `member` through `message`. Use `message.member` instead.

---

Code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('!status')) {
        const prefix = '!';
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
        if (message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
            //args[0] is the command itself
            const activity = args[1];
            client.user.setActivity(activity);
        }
        else {
            message.channel.send('Your not the Admin of the server or bot!')
        }
    }
});
```